# Android. TextInputLayout. Toggle password visibility event listener?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

There is a password visibility toggle button within TextInputLayout for InputType textPassword.

Is it somehow possible to catch toggle events?

I couldn't find any public methods for this

Comment: Not really. Well, nothing readily available, anyway. That `View` has an anonymous `OnClickListener` set on it that just calls a package-private toggle method. I can think of a couple of ways to fake it. The simplest is probably to get a reference to that `View`, and set an `OnTouchListener` on it, since you can set that up to not interfere with the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: If you can find way to access `mPasswordToggleView`, you can find solution.

Comment: @K.Sopheak I thought, maybe there is an official solution for this :) and yes, that's the way I'm trying right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at the source code of the TextInputLayout to find the type of the view of the toggle button. Its CheckableImageButton. Everything else is easy. You need to find the view iterating recursively over children of the TextInputLayout View. And then setOnTouchListener as @MikeM suggested in the comments.

```
View togglePasswordButton = findTogglePasswordButton(mTextInputLayoutView);
if (togglePasswordButton != null) {
    togglePasswordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // implementation
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private View findTogglePasswordButton(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int ind = 0; ind < childCount; ind++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(ind);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            View togglePasswordButton = findTogglePasswordButton((ViewGroup) child);
            if (togglePasswordButton != null) {
                return togglePasswordButton;
            }
        } else if (child instanceof CheckableImageButton) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

An alternative implmentation of findTogglePasswordButton

```
private View findTogglePasswordButton() {
    return findViewById(R.id.text_input_password_toggle);
}
```

@MikeM. thank you for id

Comment: That `CheckableImageButton` has an ID, apparently, if you'd rather go that route. The name is `text_input_password_toggle`, and you can get the `int` value with the `Resources#getIdentifier()` method. Just FYI.

Comment: @MikeM. good to know. Just thinking about what if they change the id?!

Comment: It's unlikely that they would, but, either way, it's a resource packaged inside your app, and you control the support library version. That is, as long as you've got the correct ID for the library version you compile with, you're good. It won't be dependent on a system resource that might differ between devices.

Comment: The alternative worked for me, however, I had to keep looking for the right id, the one described above didn't work. For me, what worked was ```val passwordToggleButton = textInputLayout.findViewById<CheckableImageButton?>(R.id.text_input_end_icon)
        passwordToggleButton?.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) // your code
            false
        }```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following since [Material Components v1.1.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0) (Kotlin):

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener {
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CheckableImageButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.ctm.core.ui.R;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

/**
 * Extended {@link TextInputLayout} allowing setting a listener when the user toggles the visibility
 * of the password.
 */
public class TextInputLayoutEx extends TextInputLayout {

    public TextInputLayoutEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextInputLayoutEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextInputLayoutEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setOnToggleShowPasswordListener(OnToggleShowPasswordListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) {
            initTogglePasswordShownListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"RestrictedApi"})
    private void initTogglePasswordShownListener(@NotNull OnToggleShowPasswordListener listener) {
        final View revealPasswordView = this.findViewById(R.id.text_input_password_toggle);
        if (revealPasswordView == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!(revealPasswordView instanceof CheckableImageButton)) {
            return;
        }

        final CheckableImageButton revealPasswordCheckableImageButton = (CheckableImageButton) revealPasswordView;
        revealPasswordView.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == motionEvent.getAction()) {
                listener.onToggleShowPasswordClicked(!revealPasswordCheckableImageButton.isChecked());
                return view.performClick();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    public interface OnToggleShowPasswordListener {
        void onToggleShowPasswordClicked(boolean isShown);
    }
}
```

In client code:

```
TextInputLayoutEx layoutPassword = (TextInputLayoutEx) findByById(...)
layoutPassword.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);
        layoutPassword.setOnToggleShowPasswordListener(isShown -> Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Password shown: " + isShown, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the View hierarchy with **Layout Inspector** I can see the following:

[image: View Hierarchy screenshot]

So you can either do:

```
val toggle = password.findViewById<CheckableImageButton?>(R.id.text_input_password_toggle)
toggle?.setOnClickListener {
    println("clicked on toggle")
}
```

or manually:

```
// Assuming you have AndroidKTX
val views = password.children
for (v in views) {
    if (v is FrameLayout) {
        val innerViews = v.children
        for (iv in innerViews) {
            if (iv is CheckableImageButton) {
                iv.setOnClickListener { 
                    println("clicked on toggle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using binding here.

This is the id of the layout - regPasswordlayout
default id of the password toggle - text_input_password_toggle

```
binding.regPasswordlayout.findViewById(R.id.text_input_password_toggle)
.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              // your code goes here
         }
     });
```