# TextInputLayout Password Toggle Listener

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout for password. I have added passwordToggleEnabled=true to toggle the password visibility. 
I need to capture the event when user toggles password visibility. How can I do this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/enter_new_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the UI component posted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264033/789110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the source of the `TextInputLayout` the type of the view of the toggle button is `CheckableImageButton`. You just need to find the view iterating recursively over children of the `TextInputLayout` View. And then `setOnTouchListener`.

```
View togglePasswordButton = findTogglePasswordButton(mTextInputLayoutView);
if (togglePasswordButton != null) {
    togglePasswordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // implementation
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private View findTogglePasswordButton(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int ind = 0; ind < childCount; ind++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(ind);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            View togglePasswordButton = findTogglePasswordButton((ViewGroup) child);
            if (togglePasswordButton != null) {
                return togglePasswordButton;
            }
        } else if (child instanceof CheckableImageButton) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How can I check if the password is visible? In both case inputtype is coming as 129

Comment: use a boolean variable isVisible for example in your onTouchListener when users clicks the toggle button switch the value of the variable accordingly (true or false). It's the best I can suggest

Comment: OK, We can use CheckableImageButton.isChecked but had to add @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi"). Else it is showing error "CheckableImageButton.ischecked can only be called from within the same library group"

Answer (score 2):

Setting only the end icon click listener like proposed in another answer won't work, because doing so will remove the existing listener which is used to toggle the `EditText` transformation method.

So if you set a new listener, you need to change it yourself:

```kotlin
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener {
    // Toggle the EditText transformation method from nothing to password or vice versa.
    // Selection is lost in the process so make sure to restore it.
    val editText = textInputLayout.editText
    val oldSelection = editText.selectionEnd
    val hidePassword = editText.transformationMethod !is PasswordTransformationMethod
    passwordEdt.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance().takeIf { hidePassword }
    if (oldSelection >= 0) {
        passwordEdt.setSelection(oldSelection)
    }

    // Do your own stuff here.
}
```

Comment: This will also play the animation of un-/crossing the eye.
`PasswordToggleEndIconDelegate` also makes a call to `textInputLayout.refreshEndIconDrawableState()` in case your icon's tint list has a color for a state that depends on a click.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer, if you are still looking for a complete solution about TextInputLayout Password Toggle Listener:

```
    public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputLayout password_input_layout;
    TextInputEditText password_edit_text;

    //textInputLayoutEndIconPressed will be tracked, EndIcon is pressed and toggled or not
    private boolean textInputLayoutEndIconPressed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textInputLayoutEndIconPressed = false;
        password_input_layout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password_input_layout);
        password_edit_text = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);

        password_input_layout.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!textInputLayoutEndIconPressed)
                    textInputLayoutEndIconPressed = true;
                else
                    textInputLayoutEndIconPressed = false;

                if(textInputLayoutEndIconPressed){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Changing Drawable file
                            password_input_layout.setEndIconDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_visibility_on));
                            //Changing TextInputEditText password text to open
                            password_edit_text.setTransformationMethod(null);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Changing Drawable file
                            password_input_layout.setEndIconDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off));
                            //Changing TextInputEditText password text to hide
                            password_edit_text.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

When you set a EndIconOnClickListener, then you need to check both TextInputEditText text status and TextInputLayout EndIcon Drawable file. So you can manage this scenario like this.

Answer (score -1):

Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487564/1254514), but in short you can do the following since [Material Components v1.1.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0) (Kotlin):

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: No, this listener will replace the listener that toggles password visibility.