# TextInputLayout: Password Toggle not working programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

Password toggle button (eye) is clickable but does not do the needed actions, I mean when I click on it; the password does not appear or hide.
In my case, when the password length is greater than or equal to 8; I want to show password toggle, and when clicking on it; the password appears or hide.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ripG.png)

```
binding.edPassword.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
        val password = binding.Password
        val edPassword = binding.edPassword
        when {
            edPassword.text?.isEmpty()!! -> {
                password.error = "enter password"
                password.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE

                binding.btnTest.isEnabled = false
            }
            edPassword.text?.length!! >= 8 -> {
                password.error = null
                password.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE

                binding.btnTest.isEnabled = true
            }
            edPassword.text?.length!! < 8 -> {
                password.error = "Password Should Not be less than 8 Character"
                password.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE

                binding.btnTest.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ripG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Should get eye toggle icon view.
Then listen on clicked.

```
View togglePasswordButton = findTogglePasswordButton(mTextInputLayoutView);
if (togglePasswordButton != null) {
    togglePasswordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // implementation
            return false;
        }
    });
}


private View findTogglePasswordButton(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int ind = 0; ind < childCount; ind++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(ind);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            View togglePasswordButton = findTogglePasswordButton((ViewGroup) child);
            if (togglePasswordButton != null) {
                return togglePasswordButton;
            }
        } else if (child instanceof CheckableImageButton) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Source:
[TextInputLayout Password Toggle Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037679/textinputlayout-password-toggle-listener)